# Why doesn't `clearTimeout` produce an error if the argument is `undefined`?

Tags: javascript

```js
function getData() {
  console.log('Fetching data');
}

const magic = (fn, delay) => {
  let timer;
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      fn();
    }, delay);
  }
}

const better = magic(getData, 3000);
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="better()" />
```

For the very first time `timer` would be `undefined` then why JavaScript doesn't give an error for that?

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: `clearTimeout` doesn't throw an error if the argument is `undefined`. That's the explanation. I'm not really sure it's worth for `clearTimeout` to work differently. Why do you expect it to?

Answer (score 2):

If you pass an *handleid* that is not present in the list of active timeouts, then the method ignores it. It doesn't throw an error.

> The clearTimeout() method must clear the entry identified as handle from the list of active timeouts of the WindowTimers object on which the method was invoked, where handle is the argument passed to the method, if any. (If handle does not identify an entry in the list of active timeouts of the WindowTimers object on which the method was invoked, **the method does nothing**.)

[Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-cleartimeout)

Comment: I hope you're OK with the edit. I personally don't mind timeout/interval distinction as there is none for most cases. However, some users are unreasonably combative when they see `interval` where they use `timeout` or vice versa. Yesterday, an asker became very angry when they wanted to do something with `setInterval` and I linked them to answers with `setTimeout`.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you. While reading through the spec, I forgot the question was about timeout and not interval. Also, it's worth pointing that `clearTimeout` and `clearInterval` can be used interchangeably. They both clear timeout or interval based on the interval id provided.

Comment: Yep, that's true. The only worthwile distinction between a timeout and interval is whether you use `setTimeout` to run something once or `setInterval` to run it (potentially) indefinitely. Other than those two calls, they behave identically even for `clearTimeout`/`clearInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `clearTimeout` also handles undefined, meaning it has something like a check within the implementation of the function e.g.

```
const clearTimeout = (timer) => {
    if (timer) {
        // logic
    }
}
```

This is probably for better and easier implementation, like you've implemented, so you don't have to worry about such stuff. If it was meant to throw error if timer is null/undefined because it would have some terrible side-effect, they'd probably implement it as

```
const clearTimeout = (timer) => {
    if (!timer) {
        throw new Error("Timer can not be undefined");
    }
}
```